# Write $\mathop {\mathbb E}[(X AX^h)]$ in function of $\mathop {\mathbb E}[(X X^h)]$?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, random-matrix

Suppose $X$ is an $i \times j$ random matrix. In addition, $X$ has complex i.i.d. normal entries with $0$ as mean. We define $A$ (of dimension $j \times j$) as a deterministic matrix.

Is it possible to express the expression $\mathop {\mathbb E}[(X AX^h)]$ in function of $\mathop {\mathbb E}[(X X^h)]$?

Comment: Perhaps $A$ is supposed to be a $j\times j$ matrix?  Pending some clarification of this crucial point, I have voted to put the question on hold.  In the meantime, why don't you consider the much easier question where (a) the matrices are all constant rather than random and (b) $i=1$ and $j=2$.  What can you say about the relationships then?

Answer (score 2):

YES, $E[XAX^h]=E[XX^h]\circ A$, where $\circ$ is for Hadamard product.

$E[XAX^h]$ mixes the columns, but since variables are i.i.d., it must that it will be function of variance $\sigma^2$ and a combination of weights in $A$.

$$M=E[XAX^h]$$
$$M_{tk}=E[\sum_{ps} X_{tp} A_{ps} X^*_{ks}]
=E[\sum_{p} X_{tp} A_{pp} X^*_{kp}]=\sigma^2\delta_{tk}A_{tk}$$
because $E[X_{ab} X^*_{cd}]=\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}\sigma^2$

Obviously, it follows that $E[XX^h]=\sigma^2I$, i.e. $E[XX^h]_{tk}=\sigma^2\delta_{tk}$

Comment: This is confusing because both $i$ and $j$ in the question are *fixed* dimensions!  (I know, that's strange, but somebody has to deal with it.)

Comment: @whuber agrred, changed the indices

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still not following the logic, though.  After correcting the final subscript $i$ to a $t,$ it looks like you are implicitly appealing to the proposition that the expectation of anything except $X_{tp}X^{*}_{tp}$ will be zero, but in that case why do it in two steps?

Comment: @whuber, the expectation matrix of interest is diagonal and proportional to the variance of X variable. that's why I'm saying it's a function, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to exactly write this without any additional information for $A$, but if we know for example that $A$ is diagonal,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(XAX^h)] = \text{trace}(A) \cdot  E[X X^h]
$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the resemblance to $E[x'Ax] = \text{trace}(A\Sigma) + \mu^TA\mu,$ for a real vector $x$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Expectation

Comment: I am  not sure what your are trying to say!

Comment: @Taylor The formula doesn't change for complex-valued variables.  Black.mirror: have you noticed that $E[XX^\prime]$ is a scalar multiple of the $i\times i$ identity matrix?